# Can I travel around Europe with an expired student visa and Italian Permeso appointment receipt? I also have the expired Permeso card, will that help?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, europe, residency

I would like to travel around Europe before I head back to India. But my student Visa has expired and my Italian stay permit is under renewal. I have the appointment receipt and the expired permit as proof. Will that be enough to travel to countries such as Germany, Budapest, France or Swiss?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible as **as the receipt only proves your legal status in Italy. you are only allowed to enter and exit the Schengen area through Italy**.

Verified by the [*Polizia di Stato website*](https://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10722-Requirements_for_immigrants_leaving_Italy_temporarily):

> Foreigners awaiting renewal of their residence permits can leave and re-enter Italy if they hold:
>
> - the receipt issued by Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A) certifying the submission of the application for
> - renewal of their residence permit or EC residence permit for
>     long-term residents;
> - the expired residence permit;
> - their passport or other equivalent travel document
>
> The same facilitated procedure is granted to foreigners who have submitted their application for their first residence permits for employment, self-employment, or family reunification, provided that:
>
> - they leave and re-enter Italy through any Italian external border crossing point (cicular letter 11th March 2009);
> - they show their passport or other equivalent travel document, along with the entry visa specifying the reasons of their stay (employment, self-employment, or family reunification ) and the receipt issued by Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A.);
> - they do not transit through other Schengen countries, as this is not allowed.

Note: **You will need to carry the receipt at all times if you do travel**.